# How to add to a floating object, several other objects, so they swam with it?

Tags: animation, constraints, groups, ocean-simulation

I made the ocean and floating object, using this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11F1NRpqrzY).

How to add to a floating object several other objects, so they swam with it? For example, how to add a mast and sail to the hull of the ship, but don't combine all of these objects into a single object?

I wanted to use constraints, and give them a "copy location" and "copy rotation" of the floating object, but I don't know how to apply these constraints to a group of objects. If I apply them individually to each object - they will move in the wrong position, and I have to move them back in edit mode. I have a lot of objects, so this is not an option.

How to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: parent them to that object  select the objects then the ship and hit Ctrl+P

Comment: @Chebhou Thank you! But why this method does not work with objects that have a cloth modifier? I tried as a test, to Parent them to empty, and sail, the ropes and the flag remained in place when I move or rotate empty.